# PHP: mPDF / pdf library / is it possible to create multiple pdf files in a loop?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mPDF library and I'm trying to write a code which will create **multiple PDF files** at one call (with one opening of: test.php). Problem: always only the first file is downloaded. I know that the question may seems stupid, I've tried to dive deep into google but I can't figure out how to solve this. Maybe someone could lead me on the right path?

My logic is:
- I have one array with all of orders; for each order I would like to create PDF. 
- I loop the array and each time call the MPDF library

**test.php**

```
$myorders = [ 
                0 => array (
                'FirstName' => 'Asia',
                'LastName' => 'Basia',
                'OrderNr' => '123'

                ), 

                1 => array (
                'FirstName' => 'Madzia',
                'LastName' => 'Siasia',
                'OrderNr' => '456'
                )
           ];

for ($i=0; $i < count($myorders); $i++) { 
    $FirstName = $myorders[$i]['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $myorders[$i]['LastName'];
    $OrderNr = $myorders[$i]['OrderNr'];
    require 'invoice.php';
}
```

**invoice.php**

```
require 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('test test' . $FirstName);
$mpdf->Output("filename{$OrderNr}.pdf",'D');
```

Only filename123.pdf is downloaded. Is it not possible to download more than one file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Think about this: Have you ever seen the behavior you are looking for anywhere? I mean, where you click on something and your browser asks if you want to save one file, then another, then a third?

Comment: You should merge the files into a single pdf or a zipfile or provide links to download each pdf separately.

Comment: Got it. I will ask another way - is it possible to create multiple pdf files in a loop using MPDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for your updated question is:

Ofcourse you can create multiple pdf files and save them onto disc. You just have to place the  pdf generation code inside your for loop.

Please refer the below mentioned code:

```
require 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';

for ($i=0; $i < count($myorders); $i++) { 
    $FirstName = $myorders[$i]['FirstName'];
    $OrderNr = $myorders[$i]['OrderNr'];
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('test test' . $FirstName);
    $mpdf->Output("filename{$OrderNr}.pdf", 'F');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you expect such feature.

You should do this using a different approach. First use the mpdf to save the files to your disc and then create a zip file and make that available for download.

Comment: 'First use the mpdf to save the files to your disc' - how can I use MPDF to create, for instance, multiple PDF files from data from one array? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
App::import('Vendor', 'mpdf', array('file' => 'mpdf' . DS . 'mpdf.php'));

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open('filename.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

if($zip->open('filename.zip'))

{

   for ($i=0; $i < count($myorders); $i++)

      {

         $FirstName = $myorders[$i]['FirstName'];

         $OrderNr = $myorders[$i]['OrderNr'];

         $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);

         $mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');

         $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

         $mpdf->setHeader('hello');

         $mpdf->WriteHTML('test test' . $FirstName);

         $content = $mpdf->Output('filename'.$OrderNr.'.pdf','F');

         $zip->addFile($content,'hellofilename'.$OrderNr.'.pdf');

   }
}

else
    {
    echo "cant open!!";exit;
    }
$zip->close();

$archfilename = 'filename.zip';

header("Content-type: application/zip"); 

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $archfilename"); 

header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

header("Expires: 0"); 

readfile("filename.zip");

exit;

?>
```

hope this helps :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to generate multiple PDF Files and save them in some directory.I used the sleep and time functions to generate unique filename so that it will overwrite existing file with same name.

```
<?php
$record = array('BMW','Mercedes','Toyota');
include_once("../lib/MPDF57/mpdf.php");
foreach($record as $value){
$filename = time().'Performance_review.pdf';
sleep(2);
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($value);
$get_pdf   = $mpdf->Output('../pdf-output/'.$filename,'F');
}?>
```