# how I print multiple pdfs in new tabs at a single click of button in mpdf, php

Tags: pdf

I am trying to make multiple PDFs from database using mPDF. I want to print the data from the database in new tabs one by one in the form of PDF.

If i do not write $mpdf->Output(), all the data from database appears in multiple new tabs correctly on browser, but when I write $mpdf->Output(); only the first PDF appears on the browser.

```
file : caller.php

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    window.open("print.php", "_blank"); 
    }
    </script>



file : print.php


<?php
session.start();

// connection made for database
//$model1 = array("mod1","mod2","mod3","mod4","mod5");

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();


$_SESSION['j']=$_SESSION['j']+1;
if($_SESSION['j']==$total) {
exit();
}


echo "<br>hardware<br>";

$asd="SELECT * FROM Hardware where Model = '".$model1[$_SESSION['j']]."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$asd);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $temp=$row["Bullets"];
    $arrr=explode("|", $temp);

    $arrlength = count($arrr);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
echo $arrr[$x];
echo "<br>";
}

}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}



for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<font style="font-size:9px"><font style="font-  family:Calibri"><b>•</b> '.$arrr[$x].' </font><br>');
}


if ( $_SESSION['j'] < $total-1 ) {
 include 'caller.php';
 }


$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

I want to print all PDFs one by one in new tabs.

Comment: Try putting `$mpdf->Output();` in the for loop just above after `$mpdf->WriteHTML`. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24385292/4442148

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't support inline PDFs; outputting a PDF will stop you outputting a web page. Instead, output a link to another PHP file with a ?query=string, and use `$_GET` to figure out which PDF to show them.

Make sure they have permission to open the PDF they're requesting!